# Combining two simple assumptions in Lean

Tags: lean

I'm trying to construct this proof in Lean:

(P → Q) ∧ (R → ¬Q) → ¬(P ∧ R)

It feels like a simple proof by contradiction:

Assume P and R, the opposite of the conclusion.

Assume P → Q. Since P, Q.

Assume R → ¬Q. Since R, ¬Q.

Q and ¬Q. Contradiction.

Here's what I've got so far in Lean:

```
example (P Q R : Prop) : (P → Q) ∧ (R → ¬Q) → ¬(P ∧ R) :=
begin
  assume a : (P → Q) ∧ (R → ¬Q),
  assume b : P ∧ R,
  cases a with pq rnq,
  cases b with p r,
  sorry
end
```

That leaves me with this goal:

```
P Q R : Prop,
pq : P → Q,
rnq : R → ¬Q,
p : P,
r : R
⊢ false
```

I feel like I should just be able to somehow combine p and pq to get Q, and combine r and rnq to get ¬Q.  But I can't figure out how to do it. If I didn't have the false in the final goal, I could just `apply pq p` and it would be done.

Ignoring this particular proof, is there a way to combine two simple hypotheses into another simple hypothesis?

Is there a different way to approach this proof? Is my theorem just wrong in some way?

Comment: try `apply rnq` :) do you know how negation is defined in lean?

Comment: I'm aware that `¬Q` = `Q→false`, but I don't understand how that's relevant here. Honestly, I'm trying to wrap my head around Lean in general, and am having a hard time. That said, I've now `apply`-ed `rnq` and now my one final goal of `false` is now two final goals of `R` and `Q`, and not only do I not understand why that is, I feel like the stuff I thought I understood has been thrown out the window. I have never felt so stupid in my life.

Comment: Okay, I think maybe I understand it a little better. I think what happened is that `R → Q → false` means that it was able to say "one way to show false is to show that R → Q, and one way to do that is to prove both R and Q". So then I was able to prove `R` by `apply R`. Then `apply pq` to show that `Q` can be proved by `P`, and then `apply p` to prove `P`. This all feels very backwards, not only from how I was thinking about it, but from how I felt like the proof construction was preceding to this point.  Regardless, thanks!

Comment: so I think the thing you may have misunderstood is how right arrows associate in Lean - `R → Q → false` is `R → (Q → false)`. In specific, `rnq r` has type `¬Q = Q → false`, which `apply` can unify with the goal. Another way to prove the last step is `exact rnq r q` (and note that this is _not_ `exact rnq (\lam hr, q)` which would be a term you could use for the type `(R → Q) → false`)

Comment: In this case, I think my issue is that I've never encountered a situation where I've applied what's effectively a double-implication to a goal. I'm going to need to construct some artificial examples to play around with to understand it better, I think.

Comment: have you heard of currying/uncurrying? `R → Q → false` is equivalent to `R × Q → false` (or in Lean for `Prop`s you'd have to write that `R ∧ Q`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the tactic you're missing here is [`have`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#have).  The `have` tactic tells Lean how to construct a new thing from what it already has, and adds it to the stock of resources in the current context.  This is what you need to "combine p and pq to get Q".

Since you have `pq : P → Q` and you have `p : P`, you can apply `pq` to `p` to get a term of `Q`.  This works just like applying a function `f : ℕ → ℤ` to a term `n : ℕ` to get a term of `ℤ`.

So you can continue your proof like this:

```
example (P Q R : Prop) : (P → Q) ∧ (R → ¬Q) → ¬(P ∧ R) :=
begin
  assume a : (P → Q) ∧ (R → ¬Q),
  assume b : P ∧ R,
  cases a with pq rnq,
  cases b with p r,
  have q : Q := pq p,
  have nq : ¬Q := rnq r,
  exact nq q,
end
```

On the last line, since we now have have `q : Q` and `nq : ¬Q` (or equivalently, `nq : Q → false`), we can apply `nq` to `q` to get a term of `false`.  But since that's the goal, we write [`exact`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#exact) here instead of `have`.

Comment: This absolutely answers my question as presented, and in a way that reaches my goal. 100%. Now I just need to understand the basic syntax better. (I'm really coming at this language from all the wrong directions.)